# Correlation between numbers and percentages

Tags: calculus, percentages

I am trying to understand the correlation, given by my data, between numbers and percentages.

I have four numbers : 1, 2, 3 and 4. And there percentages are respectively: 0, 0.3333, 0.6667 and 1.
By using a rule of 3, i'm getting : 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 and 1.

What i know from the start is that my lowest number's percentage is 0 and my highest number's percentage is 1.

If i add a number 5, i'll get the following percentages : 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 and 1.

What can replace a rule of 3 to get the right percentages ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correlation is $1$: all the points lie on an upward sloping straight line as shown here.

[image]

In statistics you could use [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) to find the line and the correlation, but this example is easier than that since the observations are colinear.  Each step of $1$ to the right takes you up by $\frac13$ so the slope is $\frac13$; a step back from $(1,0)$ then takes you to $(0,-\frac13)$ so the vertical intercept is $-\frac13$.  That gives the equation of the line as $$y=\frac13 x - \frac13$$ which you can also write as $y=\frac{x-1}{3}$.

If you knew that the line passes through $(a,0)$ and $(b,1)$ then the equation would be $y=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$, i.e. $y=\frac{1}{b-a}x -\frac{a}{b-a}$, with $a=1$ and $b=4$ in your example.

Comment: thank you so much for your help !